# Replace /usr with usr

Tags: vi

I have a text file in linux and I would like to replace /usr with usr in the whole file using vi. I tried :%s//usr/usr/ and its giving error "E488: Trailing characters".

How can I make this command work?

Comment: Have you tried *escaping* the slash? With a backslash? Like `s/\/usr/usr/`?

Comment: As the previous commenter wrote, you need to escape the slash if you use forward slashes to delimit the fields of your substitution command.  You can also use colons as delimiters as follows, in which case you should not need to escape the slash:  `:%s:/usr:usr:`

Comment: Thank you Some programmer dude and Turix, worked perfectly